# border - color not working but background - color working

Tags: html, css

So I have this validation on save that if user enters the same ranges twice against a particular type then it shows an alert with message Duplicates found. I also wanted to show red border around those text boxes with duplicates. So I added a class to those textboxes if the validation is failed. How ever it does not show me the red border.

```
 .is-invalid {
     border-color: 1px solid red;
 }

  
$(this).find('td:eq(3)').find('input').addClass("is-invalid");
```

When I change my css to

```
 .is-invalid {
   background -color:  red;
 }
```

my code :

```
  var obj = dict[CustomerTypeCode];
  if (MinVal >= obj.MinVal && MaxVal <= obj.MaxVal) {
    valid = false;
    ErrMsg = "Duplicate Ranges Found";
    alert(ErrMsg);
$(this).find("td:eq(3)").find("input").addClass("is-invalid");
  } else {
    $(this).find("td:eq(3)").find("input").removeClass("is-invalid");
  }
} else {
  dict[CustomerTypeCode] = {
    MinVal: MinVal,
    MaxVal: MaxVal
  };
```

its working fine. Why is this happening?

Comment: It's 'border: 1px solid red' not 'border-color'.

Comment: @Azu It does not work with border as well

Comment: Are you sure the class is added correctly? As far as I know it's element.classList.add()

Comment: You also have issues with spaces around your dashes

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @Azu it's jQuery

Comment: @mplungjan what issues with spaces?

Comment: `background -color:  red;` should be `background-color:  red;`

Comment: @mplungjan as i mentioned in my question that my ``background-color`` is working. The problem is with ``border``

Answer (score 0):

Should be replaced `border-color` to `border`

```css
.is-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> my background-color is working. The problem is with border

You must have another issue. My guess is that `$(this)` in your code should have been `tr` from

```
var tr = $(`#${id}`);
```

Using border works

Your row MUST be wrapped in a table

```js
$("tr").on("click", function() {
  valid = false; // from your calculations
  $(this).find("td:eq(3)").find("input").toggleClass("is-invalid", !valid);
})
```

```css
.is-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Click</td>
    <td><input value="1" /></td>
    <td><input value="2" /></td>
    <td><input value="3" /></td>
    <td><input value="4" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Like this

```js
function OnChangedAction(key, id) {
  console.log("here")
  var tr = $(`#${id}`);
  if ($.trim(tr.find("td:eq(0)").html()) != "No Data.") {
    if (dict[CustomerTypeCode]) {
      if (MinVal >= obj.MinVal && MaxVal <= obj.MaxVal) {
        valid = false;
        ErrMsg = "Duplicate Ranges Found";
        alert(ErrMsg);
      }
      tr.find("td:eq(3)").find("input").toggleClass("is-invalid", !valid);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Please see my code here. Can you modify it to add border here? https://codepen.io/burhansavci/pen/gOGLwgp

Comment: I am adding my class after this line  ``ErrMsg = "Duplicate Ranges Found";``

Comment: Your code is not complete. I get error `blockNonNumbers, extractNumber, CheckValue` not defined

Comment: I do not see any event that would trigger invalid. Please update your question here with relevant HTML and JS

Comment: Updated my question to add that part of code.

Comment: @Unknown As you can see you can simplify the code. Perhaps `$(this)` is not what you think it is?

Comment: I think you meant `tr.find` from your var

Comment: This does add class to those textboxes. So I guess ``$(this)`` is working

Comment: can you maybe edit my code so that I know what you are suggesting?

Comment: Your codepen has some serious issues. Why do you even have inline event handlers when you use jQuery?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240076/discussion-between-unknown-and-mplungjan).